# Button touchDown event and CPBPressureTouchGestureRecognizer

Tags: iphone, xcode, uibutton, selector, pressure

my code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

CPBPressureTouchGestureRecognizer* recognizer = [[CPBPressureTouchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(A_button:)];
[A_button addGestureRecognizer: recognizer];
[recognizer release];


[P2_button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[P2_button addTarget:self action:@selector(touchDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
}

- (void) A_button: (CPBPressureTouchGestureRecognizer*) recognizer {
[self.presLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",recognizer.pressure]];
}
```

and finally

```
-(IBAction)touchUp :(id)sender{
[myTimer invalidate];
myTimer = nil;
NSLog(@"up");
}

-(IBAction)touchDown :(id)sender{

myTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.1 
                                           target:self
                                         selector:@selector(A_button:) 
                                         userInfo:nil 
                                          repeats:YES]; 


}
```

but don't work, if in timer selector i whrite @selector(A_button) do nothing, and if i whrite @selector(A_button:) return error:

> 2012-02-22 22:38:24.837 TestPres[19686:707] -[__NSCFTimer pressure]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x143570
>   2012-02-22 22:38:24.847 TestPres[19686:707] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFTimer pressure]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x143570'

Where is the problem? How can display pressure value even 0.1 second when i touchDown m button?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `A_button:` method is expecting a `CPBPressureTouchGestureRecognizer` to be passed in as an argument. When your timer fires, it calls that method but passes the `NSTimer` object instead.

Also, the way the pressure gesture recognizer works is much like that of a tap gesture recognizer. Even if you kept a reference to it, it does not continuously monitor the pressure applied. It only approximates the pressure when the tap is recognized.

Comment: Also please note that mixing gesture recognizers and UIControlEvents can get a bit tricky. You have to really think about how they may interact and/or conflict with each other.

Comment: thanks, how can I see pressure data continuously (every 0.1 sec) when I hold down my UIButton?

Comment: I have not found a way to do that. The pressure gesture recognizer you're using relies on the accelerometer. A constant holding of a button would not generate the movement needed to sense pressure.